# When zooming in on my website the div's move

Tags: css, html, zooming, out

i'm new to HTML & CSS and was hoping someone could help me out. I'm having a problem with this page where content is not fixed in place and when I zoom in and out the containers move freely. Any idea how to fix this? Not sure what layout I should be using to prevent this from happening. Thanks

```
        <body>
            <img class="img" src="http://i824.photobucket.com/albums/zz162/nathanial292/banner_zps45abd080.png">    
        <div id="header">    
        <h3 id="header h3">    
             <a href="index.html">Home</a> Servers <a href="http://shoppingcart-28745.safestorefront.com/Merchant/?p1=201298">Shop</a> <a href="forum.html">Forum</a> About Us Contact    
        </h3>    
        </div>    
        <div class="left">    
            <h1>Server Updates</h1>    
            <h2><span>Hello readers</span></h2>     
        </div>    
        <div class="right">    
            <a id="nabblelink" href="http://hydronetworks-forums.58422.x6.nabble.com/">HydroNetworks Forums</a>    
        <script src="http://hydronetworks-forums.58422.x6.nabble.com/embed/f1"></script>    
        </div>    
        <div id="footer">All Rights Reserved 2013  HydroNetwork</div>    
    </body>
```

```
    #header{    
        z-index: 1;    
        border-radius: 5px;    
        height: 50px;    
        width: 600px;    
        background-color: #585858;    
        border: solid #383838 6px;    
        position: absolute;    
        margin-top: 25px;    
        margin-left:640px;    
        min-width: 480px;    
    }
    .right{
        z-index: 1;    
        border-radius: 5px;    
        height: 600px;    
        border: solid #383838 6px;    
        width: 400px;    
        background-color: #585858;    
        position: relative;    
        margin-top: 120px;    
        margin-right: 50px;    
        font-family: Ebrima;    
        overflow:auto     
    }

    .left{    
        z-index: 1;    
        border-radius: 5px;    
        height: 600px;
        border: solid #383838 6px;    
        width: 600px;    
        background-color: #585858;    
        position: relative;    
        margin-top: 120px;    
        margin-left:150px;    
        margin-right: 750px;    
        text-align: center;    
        font-family: Ebrima;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom in the content moves to the right and bottom, because you used pixel values.

At any rate you should remove
`<body background= "http://i824.photobucket.com/albums/zz162/nathanial292/background_zps477e8756.png">`
from your HTML-Code.

And add this to your CSS-Code:

```
body{
     background: url(http://i824.photobucket.com/albums/zz162/nathanial292/background_zps477e8756.png);
     background-position: top center;
}
```

If you don't want the divs to "move" when zooming, you should use percentages like `width: 50%`.

Comment: Hello i have tried using % instead of px but now i seem to have a problem with the height of my divs. It seems that it only uses the height that it needs for the text, no matter what % i change it too it stays the same.

Comment: Because you need to pay attention to the structure. If you want to fasten the height for every display, write something like this in your CSS stylessheet: html{height: 100%} body{height:100%} #container{height 30%}. The same with width. If it still doesn't work you have to define {position:relative; display:block;} for every element.